# How to separate an equation into partial fractions?

Tags: partial-fractions

I am looking at a math question that has simplified this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Can somebody explain the process for how this simplification was made?  i.e. how does the denominator get broken down to those two terms?

Comment: Numerator $1=y+1-y$

Comment: This can be done with partial fraction decomposition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way for simple or basic fractions$$\frac 1{y(1-y)}=\frac {\color{blue}{1-y}+y}{y(\color{blue}{1-y})}=\frac {1-y}{y(1-y)}+\frac y{y(1-y)}=\frac 1y+\frac 1{1-y}\color{brown}{=\frac 1y-\frac 1{y-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We write  $$ \frac {1}{y(1-y)}=\frac {A}{y}+\frac {B}{1-y}$$

Upon taking  common denominator , we get $$\frac {A(1-y)+By}{Y(1-y)}=\frac {1}{y(1-y)}$$

Therefore we want to have,$$ A(1-y)+B(y)=1$$

Let $y=1$ and we get $B=1$ and let $y=0$ to get $A=1$

Thus $$ \frac {1}{y(1-y)}=\frac {1}{y}+\frac {1}{1-y}=\frac {1}{y}-\frac {1} {y-1}     $$

Comment: Can you explain the part "Let y=1 and we get B=1 and let y=0 to get A=1"

Comment: We like to have the identity for every value of  $y$, $ A(1−y)+B(y)=1$. If you plug $y=1$ in the identity you get $A(1-1)+B(1)=1$ which is the same as $B=1$. Similarly with $y=0$